# Is this a bug in Google's batch API?

Tags: gmail-api

I had a tough time getting Google's batch API to process my gmail API requests using Mojolicious to generate the multipart HTTP request. [Please see the batch API documentation here.](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch)

After a lot of trial and error, I figured out that I had to pad one of the requests parts, a `GET` request, with a blank line (`\r\n`) after it to get Google to process it. As far as I can tell, the RFC does not require the body in a multipart message to be followed by a new line.

I'm wondering if this is a bug and if it should be reported. I'd like to spare some people all the time I lost tracking this problem down.

Please see https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1222593 for more details on how the HTTP request was generated.

Comment: Can you provide more details?  Where did you have to add padding?  Could you give an example request or a code fragment?

Comment: Please see: https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1222593. That should have the details you are looking for.

Comment: I suggest adding those details to your question here.

Comment: I think it's an issue, because I tried making a raw HTTP request using Fetch API and got errors too. Your solution worked for me.

Comment: The example in the docs contains a new line, but I still got errors if I try `application/json`